# Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

I connected to my Azure vm using ssh. I ran this command mysql -u root -p after installing mysql and phpmyadmin. Then I got:
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: while installing mysql you have some password ?

Comment: Yes, when it asked for a password I gave the password I created using sudo mysql_secure_installation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go first to your database srver in azure interface and then go to the connection security znd then you must allow it to access to azure services
and the following link gonna help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-deny-public-network-access
i hope that my answer was useful for you
good luck